# Print the value of a local variable through GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb

while debugging I need to print the value of a variable that is declared in the else block. something like this :

```
if(condition){ 

}
else {
string str = "abcd";
strcpy(globalvariable,str,sizeOf(str));
}
```

I want to see the value of str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run the program inside the debugger.
2. Set break point to stop the execution of program sequence using `break` command. In your case, `(gdb) break strcpy` to break every time it is being called strcpy in else.
3. To print you can use any of the following, `x str`, `x/s str`, `print str`, `print "%s", str`.

Comment: I just wanted to add that it may be necessary to turn off compiler optimization if you expect this variable to actually exist in the executable code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the value of `str` if `condition` is true during program flow because it does not exist in memory in this case.
You have to enter `else` block somehow, either during normal program flow or using gdb [jump](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Jumping.html#Jumping) command.